# Error in sensitivity analysis (medsens): Nonconformable Arrays

Tags: r

I am trying to run sensitivity analysis for a mediation test I ran and would appreciate feedback from anyone who might be able to identify the source of the error generated.

Mediation:

```
model.m1 <- lm(cagr_2006_2008 ~ log_pdens_06 + closeness_06 + rainfall_diff_06 + historical_drought+pct_ag_land + ag_prox + cagr_1990_2000 + historical_drought*ag_prox, data=lnd_data_c1_mediate)
summary(model.m1)
model.y1 <- glm(protest_sum_1_logit ~ log_total_pop_10 + cagr_2006_2008 + historical_drought + rainfall_diff_06, family=binomial(link="probit"), data=lnd_data_c1_mediate)
summary(model.y1)
out.1_moderate <- mediate(model.m1, model.y1, sims=1000, boot=TRUE, treat="rainfall_diff_06", mediator="cagr_2006_2008", control.value = -57.1, treat.value = 0, dropobs = TRUE)
```

Sensitivity Analysis:

```
sens.1 <- medsens(out.1_moderate, rho.by=0.05, sims=1000)
summary(sens.1)
##  Error in Mmodel.coef.sim * (rho12.sim/sigma.2.sim) %x% t(rep(1, y.k -  : 
##    non-conformable arrays
```

My code base and data sets are available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-Dh8O56oYVkSVBzc2NoTDZxNkE?usp=sharing). (If you download Regression and Mediation Analyses.R with lnd_data_c1_mediate.csv and lnd_data.csv, and select the csv file locations when prompted, the code should run smoothly. The sensitivity analyses conducted are all grouped together at the end of the file.)

Thank you very much for any information you can provide!